# Number of n-variable symmetric boolean functions that are linear

Tags: combinatorics, boolean-algebra

How many symmetric boolean functions exist that are linear? 
Let $f$ be a $n$-variable boolean function. $f$ is said to be symmetric if it is unchanged by any permutation of its variables, i.e. for 2-variable boolean functions $f$ is symmetric if $f(a,b) = f(b,a)$.
In addition $f$ is called a linear function if it does not include second- or higher degree product terms in the ring sum normal form (RSNF). For example, a 2-variable function $g(x_1, x_2)$ is linear if the RSNF is of the form $$f(x_1, x_2) = c_0 \oplus c_1 x_1 \oplus c_2 x_2$$ 
I found the number of symmetric functions as $2^{n+1}$ and the number of linear functions as $2^n$ but I'm not sure if the number of linear functions is correct. 
How do I get the number of symmetric functions that are also linear?

Comment: @D.W. I am currently preparing for entrance examinations and encountered this question in a past exam.

Comment: Thank you for the improved post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 4 symmetric linear functions.  You can easily show that you must have $c_1=c_2$ (otherwise $f(1,0,0,\dots,0)$ will be different from $f(0,1,0,\dots,0)$), and similarly, you must have $c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_n$.  $c_0$ can be anything.  Therefore, once you choose $c_0$ and $c_1$, the function is wholly determined.

You have some errors in your question.  The number of linear functions is $2^{n+1}$.  The number of symmetric functions is far higher than $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: What is the number of symmetric functions? I argued that because $f$ is symmetric it is only dependent on the number of its input variables. Because they can only take $n+1$ different values the number of symmetric boolean functions is therefore $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: @M3n4p, that is best asked separately, using the 'Ask Question' button.  I suggest counting the number of such functions with $n=4$ by hand, and comparing to your formula, to gain some partial insight.  Hint: if you have such an $f$, and I tell you that I have an input in mind with two 1's and two 0's, but I don't tell you the particular input I have in mind, is the output fully determined?

Comment: I counted all the $n = 4$ functions and it fulfills $2^{n+1}$. I don't know how you would get more?

Comment: @M3n4p, the comments here aren't intended for interactive discussion or for follow-up questions.  I would suggesting using the 'Ask Question' button to ask how many symmetric functions there are.  When you do that, show your work for how you got $2^{n+1}$ as the general formula, and how you got that number for $n=4$.